# A "singular" Tischler theorem

Tags: fibre-bundles, foliations

The [Tischler theorem](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82577795.pdf.) says that a compact manifold $M$ admitting a closed nowhere vanishing $1$-form $\alpha$ fibers over the circle. I was wondering if anything could be said about the case where $\alpha$ vanishes on some small (codimension-$1$? $0$-dimensional?) set, $sing(\alpha)$. I guess to hope for a fiber-bundle structure on $M/sing(\alpha)$ is too much, but maybe there are some extra conditions one could impose to get such a result?